# Reset Password FLOW Custom Policy with confirmation screen in AZURE B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

have set up a Sign-In custom policy in Azure AD B2C in order to customise the GUI dynamic content during the login flow and customise the branding based on certain scenarios. This sign-in policy displays a "Forgot your password?" link that is handled by my application to initiate the flow for another custom Password Reset policy.

In the standard Password Reset policies provided by B2C, once the user has reset the password, an additional screen appears indicating that the password has been successfully changed and provides a link to re-execute the sign-in policy. With the custom policy, the redirect url is immediately called after the password has been reset.

Is it possible to configure an additional step to the Password Reset policy flow with a screen that shows a confirmation message?

Comment: Not seen this before... What Password Reset policy are you using? It should have a [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-versions).

Comment: Hi @Andy are you still looking for any help?

Comment: Looking to solve this as well. @Andy - Have you found a solution?